# Playing .caf audio file with ExtAudioFileRead is not sync

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, remoteio, extaudiofileread

My app does huge data processing on audio coming from the mic input.
In order to get a "demo mode", I want to do the same thing based on a local .caf audio file.
I managed to get the audio file.
Now I am trying to use ExtAudioFileRead to read the .caf file and then do the data processing.

```
void readFile()
{
OSStatus err = noErr;

// Audio file
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"output" withExtension:@"caf"];
ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)path, &audio->audiofile);
assert(audio->audiofile);

// File's format.
AudioStreamBasicDescription fileFormat;
UInt32 size = sizeof(fileFormat);
err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audio->audiofile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &size, &fileFormat);

// tell the ExtAudioFile API what format we want samples back in
//bzero(&audio->clientFormat, sizeof(audio->clientFormat));
audio->clientFormat.mSampleRate         = SampleRate;
audio->clientFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audio->clientFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audio->clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audio->clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audio->clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;//sizeof(AudioSampleType) * 8;
audio->clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2 * audio->clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
audio->clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2 * audio->clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(audio->audiofile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(audio->clientFormat), &audio->clientFormat);

// find out how many frames we need to read
SInt64 numFrames = 0;
size = sizeof(numFrames);
err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audio->audiofile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &size, &numFrames);

// create the buffers for reading in data
AudioBufferList *bufferList = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + sizeof(AudioBuffer) * (audio->clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame - 1));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = audio->clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
for (int ii=0; ii < bufferList->mNumberBuffers; ++ii)
{
    bufferList->mBuffers[ii].mDataByteSize = sizeof(float) * (int)numFrames;
    bufferList->mBuffers[ii].mNumberChannels = 1;
    bufferList->mBuffers[ii].mData = malloc(bufferList->mBuffers[ii].mDataByteSize);
}

UInt32 maxReadFrames = 1024;
UInt32 rFrames = (UInt32)numFrames;
while(rFrames > 0)
{
    UInt32 framesToRead = (maxReadFrames > rFrames) ? rFrames : maxReadFrames;
    err = ExtAudioFileRead(audio->audiofile, &framesToRead, bufferList);
    [audio processAudio:bufferList];
    if (rFrames % SampleRate == 0)
        [audio realtimeUpdate:nil];
    rFrames = rFrames - maxReadFrames;
}

// Close the file
ExtAudioFileDispose(audio->audiofile);

// destroy the buffers
for (int ii=0; ii < bufferList->mNumberBuffers; ++ii)
{
    free(bufferList->mBuffers[ii].mData);
}
free(bufferList);
bufferList = NULL;
}
```

There is clearly something that i did not understand or that I am doing wrong with ExtAudioFileRead because this code does not work at all. I have two main problems :

1. The file is played instantaneously. I mean that 44'100 samples are clearly not equal to 1 second. My 3 minutes audio file processing is done in a few seconds...
2. During the processing, I need to update the UI. So I have a few dispatch_sync in `processaudio` and `realtimeUpdate`. This seems to be really not appreciated by ExtAudioFileRead and it freezes.
   Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is the value of `SampleRate`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is just reading samples from the file and then calling processAudio. This will be done as fast as possible. As soon as processAudio is finished the next batch of samples is read and processAudio is called again. You shouldn't assume that reading from an audio file (which is a low level and non blocking os call) takes the same time the audio read would take to play.
If you want to process the audio in the file according to the sample rate you should probably use an AUFilePlayer audio unit. This can play back the file at the right speed and you can use a callback to process the samples in real audio time instead of "as fast as possible".